# getting recommended monitor resolution

Tags: api, msdn, screen-resolution

In windows 7 when you go to change the resolution settings you can see that it highlights some recommended settings for you. This is presumable the resolutions that your monitor supports correctly.

Is there a way to get this list of recommended resolutions from windows? All I've found so far is how to get all supported resolutions, but I want the recommended ones.

Thanks

Comment: I strongly assume that the recommended resolution is just the maximum.  However, I have no source for that.

Comment: That's probably a safe guess, as long as you can be sure you aren't dealing with a CRT.  How are you getting the list of supported resolutions?