# How can I get the default/recommend monitor device mode in C# or C++?

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, windows-10, user32

I can get all monitor modes (`DEVMODEA`) by `EnumDisplaySettingsA`, e.g. as in this C# snippet:

```
public static extern int EnumDisplaySettingsA(string lpszDeviceName, int iModeNum, ref DEVMODEA lpDevMode);
```

But how can I get the default and/or recommended mode as in the settings?

[image: Display settings]

I also wonder if there is a **default mode** I can retrieve if the monitor is currently DISABLED and I have no information on which mode to enable. So one mode (resolution) which is definitely working.

PS: I am aware of this >10 years old question with no response, but things might have changed: [getting recommended monitor resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8390344/356726)

Comment: I have a 1920 x 1080 LCD monitor, but, interestingly, Windows (Win 11) 'recommends' 1024 x 768.  Well, I'd never want to run _that_, so I'm not sure if the information would be of much use to you anyway.

Comment: Yes, but I also wonder if there is a default mode I can retrieve if the monitor is currently DISABLED and I have no information on which mode to enable. I need a mode (resolution) which is guaranteed to be working at least.

Comment: Hmmm.  If it's disabled it's not usable, right?  So why change mode at all?

Comment: Nothing, absolutely nothing, in Windows is guaranteed. There are too many weird displays, too many weirder GPUs, and even more bizarre drivers. You'll need to interpret whatever output you get from the Windows API functions based on *testing*.

Comment: @Paul Sanders: I mean the disabled as "Disabled in the display settings". To extend to another display you need to disable the currently extended display and enable another

Comment: I suspect you will need to use `EnumDisplaySettingsExA`.

Comment: Aha!  Found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56080809/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-native-resolution-in-c-winapi.  The answer is in there, somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

According to [CCD Summaries and Scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/ccd-summaries-and-scenarios), The display control panel applet uses [such functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-displayconfiggetdeviceinfo).

As far as the recommended mode is concerned, use [DisplayConfigGetDeviceInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-displayconfiggetdeviceinfo#remarks) with [DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_GET_TARGET_PREFERRED_MODE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ne-wingdi-displayconfig_device_info_type).

See [QueryDisplayConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-querydisplayconfig#examples) for an example of DisplayConfigGetDeviceInfo.

Comment: Thanks!

I can get the paths and modes. But this does not give me the preferred mode completely. DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_GET_TARGET_PREFERRED_MODE. is a starter, but I also have to query the adapter for the source mode.

Also it seems that I have to get the native resolution, as some monitor offer modes higher than the native resolution.

Comment: @HorstWalter Did you solve your problem? Will you answer yourself?

Comment: It is WIP, and as it is a hobby project it will take some more time. Basically I have to try to combine some of the approaches.

1. Get the genuine resolution of the screen
2. Get the modes of the graphics card
3. Compare with the modes I have available for the target

So yes, I will update my findings, but nothing within the next days. In the meantime I have upvoted your summary, thanks. I will accept it as answer if nothing better comes up, but I am also open to new suggestions.